# Cant access spotify object

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, api, spotify

i want to display the albums of an artist that i passed from my api controller
the request is [here](http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/album.json?q=oasis).
I can access the info object, but when i access the albums object it returns undefined

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('table tr').click(function () {
        var id = this.id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/api/author/GetName/' + id,
            contentType: "text/plain charset-utf-8",
            data: id,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                getDetails(data.name);

            }
        });
        }

    );
});//End ready
function getDetails(art) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q='+ art ,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

            $('#summaryDisplay').empty();
            $('#summaryDisplay').append((JSON.stringify(data.albums)) + '<br/>');

            alert(JSON.stringify(data.info));
        },
        error: function (data) {
            $('#summaryDisplay').html('<h3>Error in retrieval</h3>');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the wrong URL in your code. Use `album` instead of `track`.

```
{
    // [...]
    url: 'http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/album.json?q='+ art,
    // [...]
}
```

Comment: sorry, i must of press back too many times when i was tidying the code for here, that was meant to be album, do i have to do a loop through the objects because there is more than one? still comes up undefined

Comment: Only changing from `track` to `album` worked for me. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/omtwc9eq/).

Comment: seems i did have to loop, thanks mate for your response